Setting table column width not working as expected with calc
    <thead className="border">
          <tr className="border *:border *:p-2">
            <th className="relative" style={{width: "50px"}}>
              Some
              <div
                className="absolute top-0 right-0 translate-x-1/2 w-[40px] h-full cursor-col-resize flex flex-col justify-center items-center opacity-0 hover:opacity-100"
                onMouseDown={(e) => {
                  setColResizing(true);
                  setColResizingIndex(0);
                  setColResizingStart(e.clientX);
                }}
              >
                {"|  |"}
              </div>
            </th>
            <th className="relative" style={{width: "calc(100% / 3)"}}>
              Some
              <div className="absolute top-0 right-0 translate-x-1/2 w-[40px] h-full cursor-col-resize flex flex-col justify-center items-center opacity-0 hover:opacity-100">
                {/* <MoveHorizontal size={20} />
                 */}
                {"|  |"}
              </div>
            </th>
            <th className="relative" style={{width: "calc(100% / 3)"}}>Some</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>

In the code above, I've set all three table headers to have different widths, but they appear to have the same width when i look in the browser, When I set all three of them to have pixel values i.e. something like width: "XXXpx", then they appear to have different widths. I've set the table layout to fixed. Additionally, the table's total width has been set to 1000px by it's parent div.
What I ultimately want to be able to do is set each element's width to be something like -
width: calc(100% / 3 + XXXpx)
Where the XXXpx is something I can change dynamically to implement a feature where the user can the change the column width based on what they want.

When you use table-layout: fixed, if you fix all cols's width, some col(s) will be changed size if not meet the total width, same with more than total width. Give one col auto and it may work.
